# JS error : net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I m trying to export a function from the **weather.js** file and use it in my **index.js** file but I get this error : net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) in the console when I try to log the `res.data`

This is my index.js file:

```
import {getWeather} from './weather';

getWeather(10, 10, Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone).then(
    (res) => console.log(res.data)
);
```

This is my weather.js file:

```
export function getWeather(lat, lon, timezone) {
    return axios.get(
        'https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?hourly=temperature_2m,apparent_temperature,precipitation,weathercode,windspeed_10m&daily=weathercode,temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,apparent_temperature_max,apparent_temperature_min,precipitation_sum&current_weather=true&precipitation_unit=inch&timeformat=unixtime',
        {
            params: {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: lon,
                timezone,
            },
        }
    );
}
```

I have included the index.js file in the script tag in head of the HTML with `type = "module"` and `defer`

Any help would be gratefull.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this is a **question** and answer site. You can see [ask] for guidance. Note: ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

Is the weather.js file in the same directory as the index.js file. If not you can move it or specify the path to the file when importing the function.

Comment: yes it is in the same directory as index.js file